# What is the error in this proof about compact operators?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Assume $C:U\to V$ is compact and $\|M_nx-Mx\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $x\in X$.

$\begin{aligned}
\|CM_n-CM\|&=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|(CM_n-CM)x\|\\
&\leq\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|C\|\|M_nx-Mx\|\\
&\to 0
\end{aligned}$

as $n\to\infty$ since $\|C\|<\infty$.

There is supposed to be an error in the above proof but I can't seem to find it.

All the spaces $X,U,V$ are Banach spaces.

Comment: The fact that $||M_nx-Mx||\to0$ for every $x$ does not imply that $\sup_{||x||=1}||M_nx-Mx||\to0$. I can't imagine why you'd think it did, to tell you the truth...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Indeed, this is really the distinction between pointwise and uniform convergence.  A fundamental issue in analysis.

Comment: Hint for a correct proof of what I imagine you're trying to prove: Your argument would be correct (with perhaps some justification needed) if $X$ were finite-dimensional...

Comment: Are the $M_n$ bounded operators?

Comment: @LutzL Why does that matter?

Comment: @LutzL Oh. Of course it matters to the correct proof - I don't see why it matters regarding why the posted proof is wrong.